# Include multiple Webpages in one sheet

Tags: excel, html, vba

I'm trying to include a few webpages into an Excel-Sheet using a macro. I managed to include multiple OLEObjects, but I then don't know how to address those properly to show the webpages that I want. The webpages show a Google Maps page, and I basically just want to display the map below a table that I query from a database. This is what I have so far.

```
For Each vTrip In lTrips

    ... some more code here

    vRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 2
    Range("A" & vRow).Select
    With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Shell.Explorer.2", _
       Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=0, Top:=vPos, Width:=600, Height:=250)
    End With

    vRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 20
    vPos = vPos + 350

Next
```

Now how can I call the following when I have multiple Objects:

```
    WebBrowser1.Navigate "http://www.website.com/page.asp?T=" & vTrip.Value
```

If I call it like this, I get an error message saying "Run-time error '424': Object required". As it seems, I can only navigate to a page within the Sheet. As I delete and recreate the sheet every time, this poses a problem as to how to define/insert the macro into the sheet after I recreated it?

Even if I could call it, how would I call it multiple times changing the 1 in WebBrowser1 to 2, 3, etc.?

Is this even possible?

Comment: Another small issue is, that those objects are not printed, although they have the property "Print object" ticked.

Comment: `WebBrowser1.Object.Navigate` should correct your error message. You shouldn't have to define/insert a macro into a sheet after recreating it. It would be a better idea to define a sheet based on the name of the sheet you'll be re-creating and placing your code in `ThisWorkbook` module instead of using `ActiveSheet`

Comment: For example `Dim ReCreateThisSheet As Worksheet` and then switch your `With` statement to `With ReCreateThisSheet.OLEObjects...`

Comment: Dan, thanks for your replies. the     WebBroswer1.Object.Navigate     did not do the trick.

Comment: @Dan, thanks for your replies. the `WebBroswer1.Object.Navigate` did not do the trick.
I'm not very good with VBA, so Im not quite sure what you mean with the `ReCreateThisSheet.OLEObjects...`.
Also, how can I control the number of Objects, as I have a variable amount of those objects that I need to place, somewhere from 1 to probably 6 to 7, but it could possibly be also higher.